# Create valid command from a string - Python

Tags: python, string, python-os

I'm writing a Python script and trying to construct a command to execute through os.system(), but I can't seem to create a valid string. I've added backslashes to escape the single (') and double quotes (") but can't get it to line up. Is it possible to escape both single quotes so that they're included in the command?

```
cmd1 = 'curl -H \'Authorization: Token token=\"12345\"\' https://analytics.radiusnetworks.com/api/v1/exports/123 > results.json'
os.system(cmd1)
```

Comment: check out python's triple quotes: `""" this escapes single(') and double(") quotes. """`

Comment: Also, as a debug method that will probably help you in many more cases than this specific one, try printing the string, then copy the printed result and try it on your command line directly to see what's the OS complaining about.

Comment: and just in case you ever need to use nested triple quotes: `'''"""This is getting ridiculous."""'''` For example: `eval("""f'''{__name__}'''""")` (python 3.6 only)

Comment: What's the problem? exactly? Because >>> import os
>>> os.system(cmd1)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    28    0    28    0     0     25      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    25
0
>>>  

And results.json contains: {"error":"401 Unauthorized"} . What's the error you get?

Comment: I tried the triple quotes " and ' and neither seemed to work. It's really the single quote after the token that is ending the string, so the endpoint isn't being included in the string. And I omitted the real tokens and endpoints so this actual command gets an authorization error.

Comment: Maybe there's different shells underneath the `/bin/sh` called by `os.system`. What is the output of `os.system('readlink --canonicalize $(which $0)')`? For me it's `/bin/dash` and your escaped string works fine as `os.system` argument.